# iOS Firebase crashlytics dashboard does not show crashes when app archived and installed via Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I setup Firebase and Crashlytics via cocoapods:

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '11.0'

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.2'
```

For debug builds, reporting works fine both for simulators and devices, I can see in the dashboard all crashed reported.

For release builds though, archived with Xcode 10.2.1, eg distributed via Testflight, I don't get any reports in the dashboard.

What can go wrong here? How can I debug this?

PS: DWARF with dSYM file is selected for release builds

Comment: Did you upload the DSYMs generated by Apple to Testflight? AFAIK you'll have to do that manually to get symbolicated crash reports.

Comment: @Gereon How would you do that?

Comment: `upload-symbols` is part of the Crashlytics toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that automating upload of dSYM does not work for bitcode enabled apps and firebase docs do not mention at the moment that we have to upload the dSYMs manually. Issue is already reported: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2901

To upload the uptodate dSYMs, fetch them first from your app store connect:
[image]

and upload them from your firebase crashlytics dashboard:
[image]

Comment: Where is the firebase crashlytics dashboard? when I click on Crashlytics I see a different screen with no tabs, just info about crashes

Comment: From the navigation menu on the left side, click on Crashlytics under the Quality section and then make sure you have an iOS app selected from the dropdown menu next to the `Crashlytics` header, the tabs do not appear for the android apps.
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/xW5YoB7

Comment: Got it, I had both IOS and Android selected, and then the tab didn't appear.